# Using case insensitive identifiers in MySQL at session level

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, odbc, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I have inherited a web application that uses MySQL as database. The previous owners were running MySQL on Windows, which is case insensitive against table/column/alias identifiers.

Our most powerful cloud MySQL server is Linux, and we are not going to buy new virtual hardware. Linux MySQL is case sensitive.

One of the queries uses different-case identifier, exactly `AND d.D11 IS NOT NULL and D.D11 <>''`.

### Changing the query(es) is not an option

Spoiler below for the curious, but no discussion please: the straight question is in the next section. This "spoiler" is to avoid the comment "*can't you just change your query?*"

> Why we cannot change the queries:

> Queries are stored __encrypted__ in a database table. They are loaded and fired when needed. These queries were designed and certified in cooperation with a lawyer's office. They are a valuable asset and while I can debug the code and catch the exact query, I can't modify it. Even if the application features a screen where I can manually edit the text of the 180 queries (having a superuser account), when that page loads the query itself is fired for some reason (being an editor screen, the query should be only loaded from its table) so the application crashes.
> Finally: I don't currently know __how many__ queries are affected by this problem

### Changing `lower_case_table_names` on a production server is not yet an option

However, changing anything at database level is a great option (via `ALTER SCHEMA`/`ALTER DATABASE`).

For now, my question is: can I tell the connection string to temporarily enable `lower_case_table_names`? If not, can I use a different character set (current is `latin1`) to have MySQL case-insensitively compare identifiers?

Comment: Just to say, but when you load and decrypt the query from your table can't you add a ToLower to your code and use the resulting text if your app runs against the Linux server?

Comment: I'm going to install the app on a Windows DB, change query casing from UI and dump. Using a ToLower() will break placeholders (which are uppercase and hardcoded both in queries and code). I'll ask the laywer to "validate" the query using a lower case table alias :-)

Comment: Yes, at this point, this seems to be the least damaging exit strategy. Hope for you to have a 'laywer' with some IT background :-)