# Telling MySQL from SQL Server in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

I understand this question looks odd because EF takes care of LINQ to SQL translation, but I'm maintaining an application in which [queries are hardcoded and encrypted in the database itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633938/using-case-insensitive-identifiers-in-mysql-at-session-level) (and written by a lawyer who certifies their correctness).

Basically I can fire the SQL text using `DbContext.Database.Connection` object, but these queries are written in a dialect-agnostic format. So the code performs a token substitution based on an `if` case bound to a configuration variable

```
if (Configuration.DbType == DbType.MYSQL)
    query = ReplaceForMySQL(query);
if (Configuration.DbType == DbType.SQLSERVER)
    query = ReplaceForSqlServer(query);
```

I can either leave the code as it is or *get rid* of the `DbType` parameter from the `Web.config`.

DB is bound using EF connection string. How can I tell what DBMS is currently in use? For example, in NHibernate I could test the dialect from the `ISessionFactory` or the `Configuration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest way would be

```
context.Database.Connection.GetType().Name
```

where `context` is a `DbContext` instance. This gives you the actual type of the `DbConnection` that's used by EF, from which you can easily tell which provider is in play.

(If this is correct please have it certified with your lawyer ﾂ)

Comment: For the lawyer's sake I'm  going to set up an automated test suite to compare results from the old version to the new one

Comment: You shouldn't need a lawyer to do that. A bit of common sense is enough.